# Tinkerpop path() step equivalent in OrientDB SQL

Tags: orientdb, tinkerpop3

I have the following working query in Tinkerpop/Gremlin that can return an ordered list of elements traversed until current step.. How can I make a similar one in OrientDB SQL?

`g.V().hasLabel('Firma').has('cui','13904073').until(hasLabel('Persoana')).repeat(inE('Actionar').otherV()).sack().path()`

I did a similar traverse using MATCH in OrientDB but i can't find a way to get the ordered list of elements traversed:

`MATCH{class:Firma,as: FirmaBaza,where:(cui=13904073)}.(inE("Actionar") {as:actEdge}.outV()) {as:act,where:($matched.FirmaBaza!= $currentMatch and @class=="Firma"),while:(true)}.in("Actionar") {as:actPers,where:(@class=="Persoana")} return $pathElements`

Is there any way to get the ordered list of traversed elements using OrientDB SQL ?

Comment: OrientDB supports gremlin queries. Why not running the working gremlin query?

Comment: @Kfir Dadosh Yes...but I am trying to stick to OrientDB SQL because its usually  faster than Gremlin queries.